# How to Retrieve large data from Salesforce using Rest API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, rest, apex-webservice

I have one new requirement where My client wants to retrieve large data set (~80K records) from Salesforce daily. I have created rest web service but it returns only 2k records.

for 80k records, do client needs to call 40 times in a day to retrieve all records?

Please can you share your inputs on above?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the **Bulk API**

- [Introduction to Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)
- [Bulk Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_bulk_query_intro.htm)
- [Walk Through a Bulk Query Sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm)
- [Trailhead: Using Bulk API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk)

Answer (score 0):

With the [Composite Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) you can [technically retrieve up to 60k records only two request](https://medium.com/@charlie_77818/querying-large-ish-datasets-fast-and-efficiently-with-salesforces-composite-resources-3f614dbca111?source=friends_link&sk=71c1fd94db7a8b80a237991376259eeb)!

This is a bit of a cheat in that it relies on "guessing" the `nextRecordsUrl` of the query and only works without child relationships.

In those cases, you can still leverage Composite API to reliably pull down 10k records per query.

Doing so would look something like this:

```json
{
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "/services/data/v42.0/query?SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account",
            "referenceId": "req1",
        },
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "referenceId": "req2",
            "url": "@{req1.nextRecordsUrl}"
        },
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "referenceId": "req3",
            "url": "@{req2.nextRecordsUrl}"
        },
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "referenceId": "req4",
            "url": "@{req3.nextRecordsUrl}"
        },
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "@{req4.nextRecordsUrl}"
        }
    ]
}
```